# RelativeLayout onClickListener crashes my app

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am a beginner in android development and i can't find a solution to this problem.
I want do do something when the screen is pressed, no matter where.

My code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then app crashes exactly when the activity is created. 
If i remove the listener part it works as it should.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't inflated your layout. You need something like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout); // this guy here

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Your `RelativeLayout` lives inside of your layout file and since you haven't inflated it with `setContentView()`, `findViewById()` returns null. This causes a `NPE` when you try to set the listener on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you call setContentView method with R.layout.your_file_name before your findViewById call